# Get dynamic path url using php?

Tags: php

Get dynamic path url using php ?

I have 2 type of url like this:

type 1 : `https://www.example.com/person/1`

type 2 : `https://www.example.com/search/word/1`

so I want to get `https://www.example.com/person/` from type 1

and I want to get `https://www.example.com/search/word/` from type 2

How can I do that with single php code?

Comment: That mean you want to remove digit from end of URL string?

Comment: yes remove digit ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove last part of string. The regex select digit at the end of url and remove it.

```
$url = preg_replace("/\d+$/", "", $url);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/WTZg3)